# Добавление Windows в GRUB2

Tags: windows, debian, grub, dual-boot

Установил Debian 6.0.5 поверх Windows XP. Не появилось меню выбора Windows в grub. Я понимаю, что здесь не форум экстрасенсов, но другой информации нет... Спрашивайте, я постараюсь ответить в краткие сроки.

Всем спасибо,после небольших танцев с бубном я сделал:
добавил Windows в `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` и на выходе получил:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ***###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Windows" {
    set root=(hd0,2)
    chainloader +1
}
```

Еще крупная ошибка, это забывал прописать **update-grub** и ставить символ "**}**"

Comment: Что значит "поверх Windows XP"? У вас там был один раздел?

Comment: Как понять один раздел?Была винда,установил дебиан,все

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хотя править в ручную конфиги grub не рекомендуется, все же советую это сделать, ибо меня спасло только это.

```
 # nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Далее после записей дебиан прописать что-то вроде следующего:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
 menuentry "Microsoft Windows XP Professional RU (on /dev/sda1)" {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ntfs
        set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set f6209cff209cc84f
        drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
        chainloader +1
}

 ### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

Значение "/dev/sda1" - раздел с Windows, "f6209cff209cc84f" - это UUID этого раздела.

Comment: вы фактически оказались правы

Answer (score 1):

А вообще попробуй перегенерировать список, командой

`update-grub`

или

`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: Это все я уже пробовал(